# How to safely render html in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I've got some user generated html markup from a text area and I'd like to render it on another part of the screen. The markup is saved as a string in the props of the component.

I don't want to use dangerouslysethtml for obvious reasons. Is there a parser such as [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) but for html so that it strips out script tags and other invalid html.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Sanitize the html using the [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) module, and render the sanitized string using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

You can create a simple wrapper component:

```
const defaultOptions = {
  allowedTags: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ],
  allowedAttributes: {
    'a': [ 'href' ]
  },
  allowedIframeHostnames: ['www.youtube.com']
};

const sanitize = (dirty, options) => ({
  __html: sanitizeHtml(
    dirty, 
    options: { ...defaultOptions, ...options }
  )
});

const SanitizeHTML = ({ html, options }) => (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={sanitize(html, options)} />
);
```

**Usage:**

```
<SanitizeHTML html="<img src=x onerror=alert('img') />" />
```

---

You can also use [react-sanitized-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sanitized-html)'s SanitizedHTML component, which is a react wrapper around `sanitize-html`:

```
<SanitizedHTML
  allowedAttributes={{ 'a': ['href'] }}
  allowedTags={['a']}
  html={ `<a href="http://bing.com/">Bing</a>` }
/>
```

Comment: I don't understand how `react-sanitized-html@2.0.0` is just 2kb if is a wrapper of `sanitize-html`, when `sanitize-html@1.20.0` is 157.2kB :/ !

Comment: Ok, because is needed to install both packages for separate... react-sanitized-html and sanitize-html :/

Comment: Because sanitize-html is a peer dependency, and not actual part of the package.

Comment: Hi there @ori , I'm following ur instruciton but i got error on my compiler 
`[11:40:00] Starting 'browserify_typescript'...
[11:40:04] 'browserify_typescript' errored after 4.29 s
[11:40:04] Error in plugin 'gulp-browserify'
module "./tagtypes" not found from "/d/myProject/web/node_modules/sanitize-html/dist/sanitize-html.js"`
it said ./tagtypes not found

Comment: This is a build related issue. You should open a new question.

Answer (score 32):

An example based on the accepted answer:

```
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';

const MyComponent = () => {
  dirty = '<a href="my-slug" target="_blank" onClick="evil()">click</a>';
  const clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, {
    allowedTags: ['b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a'],
    allowedAttributes: {
      a: ['href', 'target']
    }
  });
  return (
    <div 
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: clean}}
    />
  );
};
```

`MyComponent` renders `div` containing the link without `onClick="evil()"`:

```
<a href="my-slug" target="_blank">click</a>
```

Answer (score 18):

For XSS filtering, there is a good alternative to [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) written by security people, called [dompurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify).

Here is how the wrapper from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663813/1762849 would look with DOMPurify:

```js
const defaultOptions = {
  ALLOWED_TAGS: [ 'b', 'i', 'em', 'strong', 'a' ], 
  ALLOWED_ATTR: ['href']
};

const sanitize = (dirty, options) => ({
  __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(
    dirty, 
    { ...defaultOptions, ...options }
  )
});

const SanitizeHTML = ({ html, options }) => (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={sanitize(html, options)} />
);
```

Usage:

```js
<SanitizeHTML html="<img src=x onerror=alert('img') />" />
```

---

Also, if you you need to sanitize HTML on client and server, consider using the [isomophic-dompurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-dompurify) module which unifies use of DOMPurify on frontend and backend.

Comment: This seems like a better alternative as it gives just what's needed @15kB https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=dompurify@2.1.1

Comment: is there any way to 'initialize the sanitizer inside the component'? for example, to lazy load it? it will not be able to lazy load with it as a global i think