# Validate input HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I need to validate HTML user input in a web App using JavaScript.

What I did so far based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663751/how-to-safely-render-html-in-react): I'm using third party library, [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html), to sanitize input and then compare it to original one. If they are different, Html is invalid.

```
const isValidHtml = (html: string): boolean => {
    let sanitized = sanitizeHtml(html, sanitizationConfig);
    sanitized = sanitized.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/<br>|<br\/>/g, ''); // different browser's behavior for <br>
    html = html.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/<br>|<br\/>/g, '');
    return sanitized === html;
}
```

The above method works fine with unescaped Html but not with escaped ones.

```
isValidHtml('<'); // false
isValidHtml('&lt;'); // true
isValidHtml('<script>'); // false
isValidHtml('&lt;script&gt;'); // true, this should be false also!!!
```

1. Am I missing something with this method?
2. Is there a better way to do this task?

**EDIT:**
As suggested by @brad in the comments, I tried to decode Html first:

```
decodeHtml(html: string): string {
    const txt = document.createElement('textarea');
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    const decodedHtml = txt.value;
    txt.textContent = null;
    return decodedHtml;
}
```

and then call `isValid(decodedHtml)`, I got this result:

```
isValidHtml('<'); // false
isValidHtml('&lt;'); // false, this should be true!!!
isValidHtml('<script>'); // false
isValidHtml('&lt;script&gt;'); // false
```

Comment: Why not just let the browser parse it, and then re-serialize the DOM to HTML?  Whatever you do, RegEx isn't the answer.

Comment: @Brad If I do so, `&lt;` will be decoded as `<` and `sanitizeHtml` method will return empty string. Which means `isValid('&lt;')` returns false

Comment: No it won't... did you try it?

Comment: @Brad I did update my question, is that what you are suggestion?

Comment: Your code is not Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not actually trying to validate the HTML, and are simply trying to ensure it ends up being valid, I would recommend running it through the DOM parser and getting the HTML back out, effectively letting the browser do the work for you.

Untested, but something like this:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Basically, you use the browser's built-in parsing to handle any errors, in the standard way that it does anyway.  It will create a tree of nodes.  From that tree of nodes, you generate HTML that is guaranteed to be valid.

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Parsing_an_SVG_or_HTML_document