# How to use DOMpurify?

Tags: reactjs, sanitize, dompurify

Also I try to use React Stack Snippet but that doesn't work. It's the first time for me so I need help for sure

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: sampleText,
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const text = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ text: text });
  };

  renderText = (text) => marked(text, { sanitize: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <textarea
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.text}
              className="form-control"
              rows="35"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: this.renderText(this.state.text),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I realised an edit markdown.
I would like replace "sanitize" by DOMPurify. How can I do that ?
I showned this page :
[enter link description here](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)
but I don't know how to adapt my code.
I hope It's clear enougth

```
import './App.css';
import { sampleText } from './sampleText';
import { marked } from 'marked';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: sampleText,
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const text = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ text: text });
  };

  renderText = (text) => marked(text, { sanitize: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <textarea
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.text}
              className="form-control"
              rows="35"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: this.renderText(this.state.text),
              }}
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This [answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663751/how-to-safely-render-html-in-react helped me to use `DomPurify`.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: this.renderText(this.state.text),
}}
```

with
`// import purify from “dompurify”;

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:purify.sanitize(this.state.text, { sanitize: true }) }} />`
```